# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dataTransfer')

Tags: javascript

I meet this issue while dragging and dropping images into an area

**JS CODE:**

```
function dropHandler(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  const target = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
  this.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
    if(node !== target) return;
      console.log(event.dataTransfer.files)
    });        
}

function eventHandler(element, eventType, callback) {
return document.getElementById(element).addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
}

eventHandler('app', 'drop', dropHandler);
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="1" class="drop-zone">
  <span style="pointer-events: none">Drag and drop a file here<span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.drop-zone{
border: 1px dahsed #ccc;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 cursor:pointer"
}

.drop-area--over{
border-style:solid;
}
```

from where this issue comes up?

Comment: `target = document.getElementById(event.target.id)` makes no sense, that should be just `target = event.target`!

Comment: It's [`event.dataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/dataTransfer) not `node.dataTransfer`. Though it's not really clear what you meant that loop to do at all.

Comment: @Bergi The loop is for the other input the block div.id.app contains 4 inputs. I did not include them to not make the code to long

Comment: @Bergi the same error comes up with event.dataTransfer.files

Comment: Really, `event` is `undefined`? Surely it would at least change the error mesage.